# Term for a bullet hitting a bystander in a gunfight

Tags: meaning, word-choice

What is the term for a bullet hitting a bystander in a gunfight?

When it misses the intended target and hits a bystander.

Comment: "Collateral damage" is the US military euphemism.

Comment: Note __collateral damage__ as you said would _only_ be used by the military.  The news wouldn't report a gangster's stray bullet hitting a bystander as "collateral damage"

Comment: all the voting in this Q&A is like a gunfight, maybe some of them were like 'a bullet hitting a bystander' ;)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

*Crossfire* would describe the entire scene. From the OED:

> gunfire from two or more directions passing through the same area, often killing or wounding noncombatants: *a photographer was killed in the crossfire*.

The bullet itself would be described as a *stray* bullet. From the OED:

> move without a specific purpose or by mistake, esp. so as to get lost or arrive somewhere where one should not be

Comment: Crossfire would imply that two or more opposing parties are exchanging gunfire, and that the bystander was located directly in between them. I think the term “stray bullet” would work for a much broader range of scenarios. That's just my interpretation though.

Comment: @Doresoom I agree that *stray bullet* would work for a broader range of scenarios. But OP specifically used the word [*gunfight*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/gunfight), which would require more than one shooter.

Comment: [A gunfight can involve only one person](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090502222645AAh9OpS)

Comment: @NewAlexandria I'm sorry but I don't see how that link demonstrates that a gunfight can involve only one person. Also, both [Mirriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gunfight) and the OED (*a fight involving an exchange of fire with guns*) specify *guns*.

Comment: The number of combatants is not relevant. Crossfire in no way implies an accidental shooting. In fact crossfire is the main purpose of the 4 Fs (find, fix, flank, finish). `Stray bullet` is a far more suitable choice for the stated question.

Comment: @amacy the [OED defines a gunfight in broader manner](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/89857/can-a-gunfight-happen-when-only-one-person-has-a-gun), generalizing it to any shooting attack.

Comment: @horatio "hitting a bystander [with a bullet]" is not called a "stray bullet" - the thing that *hits* the bystander **is** a `stray bullet`.  Sounds like OP is looking for a verb, not a noun.  You are correct that the number of combatants involved is not relevant.

Comment: While one can be hit accidentally in the crossfire, there can be crossfire without anyone getting hit. So clearly, the term for a bystander getting hit is not *crossfire*.

Answer (score 45):

I think the word you're looking for is *stray*, which means to deviate from the desired course.

> The bystander was hit by stray gunfire.

or

> A stray bullet struck a bystander.

Comment: Google Books confirmed my suspicions on this one - **a stray bullet** is some 200 times more common than **stray gunfire**, which latter sounds decidedly odd to my ear.

Comment: yea I agree. stray gunfire doesn't sound right.

Comment: Well you wrote it! Not that I'm downvoting the answer, but I think amacy's is better because it includes *crossfire* as well (not necessarily good for OP's "lone gunman" context, but closely related).

Comment: lol, no problem. "The bystander was hit multiple times by stray gunfire" or "Multiple stray bullets struck the bystander". I think I prefer the first one in this example.

Comment: I think this describes the imprecision of the shooter, not the striking of a bystander.

Answer (score 11):

This is called [Collateral Damage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collateral_damage).

Comment: missed StoneyB's comment-answer.  It's the term that most-directly addresses the *hitting* of a non-target by a bullet (or other attack).   I don't think that there is any term that more-directly denotes this *hitting* specific to gunfire.

Comment: Collateral Damage is more about damage that happens in addition to the intended damage.  Like with a bomb that hits its target.  This is a miss

Comment: @Chad it's true, given usage.  Specifically, collateral references 'concomitant' matters in the definition, so perhaps its not too far off.

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about an actual gunfight, as in two groups exchange gunfire, then the appropriate term would be *crossfire* as in *caught in the crossfire*.

While the term may technically mean somebody between the two groups, colloquial use will often include people that are merely within a reasonable area of conflict.

*Collateral Damage* is a US military concept, and while it does apply to what you are talking, it also applies to other actions that can injure or kill innocent bystanders. e.g. "The soldiers did not call in an air strike, as there would be too much collateral damage"

Comment: Welcome to the site! This answer is rather similar to one or more answers already given.  Also, be keen to the subtleties of the questions, particularly when your first thoughts are already present in others answer - and none are yet accepted.  It often means the OP is asking something else. In this case, the OP is asking for a *verb* that means 'hitting' in context to gunfights.