# "also is" at the end of sentence

Tags: grammaticality, verbs

> I am in favour of compromises and I am glad that Gabriel also is.

Is it okay here to end the sentence with "also is"? Is there a better/more proper way to express this?

Comment: Your sentence is perfectly fine. What makes you think that it's wrong? It would be good if you could explain your reasoning, or this might get closed.

Comment: Personally, I would say *is also.* (or better *is, as well.*); but that'a a matter of style.

Comment: I don't think I heard this construction before, and googling didn't reveal any examples either. But I'm not a native speaker, that's why I decided to ask here. In any case the answer "Yes" from someone who knows English better than me would answer my question. I don't see any reason to close it.

Comment: It depends what you mean by _OK_.

Comment: @TimLymington: I think you're in good company there! I just checked Google Books for ["also is but"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22also+is+but%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) (10K hits) and ["is also but"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22is+also+but%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) (266K hits). I figure appending "but" means that a large proportion of the hits will be starting a new sentence (or at least, new *clause*) at that word. In short, OP's sequence "also is" looks decidedly "non-standard", regardless of any grammatical considerations that might affect things.

Comment: @JSBձոգչ: There are already several upvotes for Tim's comment saying *is also* is "better". Even if no-one can justify thinking that, the fact that there seems to be a marked preference seems like a perfectly good reason for asking "why is that"?

Comment: @FumbleFingers  'Cause that's how we say it. Sometimes we write it different, but that's how we say it.

Comment: @StoneyB: Even if it were true that there's no meaningful reason (or more accurately, "no currently-identifiable reason"), that wouldn't make it a bad question. Personally, I believe that very little about language usage is truly "happenstance". It's like the weather - we just don't know enough about the details to explain much of what happens. If we knew more about what's going on, we'd perceive far less "randomness" in the process.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Fersher. My stab in the dark is that it's metric: the postposited long monosyllable is better for ending phrases/clauses, while the preposited trochee gives a stronger pick-up for a following stress.

Comment: @StoneyB: I often think you overplay prosody at the expense of semantics, and the tendency of speakers to "unify/regularise" structures. I could go with the idea that **is too** gets a boost from the fact that it presents the ideal vowel to *emphasise* at the end of a statement, but I can't see "spoken metre" being significant in the preference between *is also* and *also is*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Well, I was an actor for 30 years. But no, it's not operative in OP's example, which is pretty clunky either way. I'm thinking more of ordinary use: *John's driving too*, but *John's also driving*. I'm not saying it's determinative, just a push in that direction.

Comment: @StoneyB: I think the prosody "push" in this case would be negligible in comparison to the natural tendency to put the more *significant* word ("also", or "too") at the end - where it stands out more automatically, and is easier to give additional emphasis if you want. Ending with a piffling verb form like "is" has little going for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sentence is grammatical, but not very idiomatic, at least in US English. My impression is that in ordinary speech:

- *too* is used most frequently, almost always at the end of the clause:

> > Bob's driving, and John's driving too. *or* Bob's driving. John too.
> >     Bob's driving, and he's buying the food, too.

- *also* is used less often and is usually put before the added element:

> > Bob's driving, and also John. *or* Bob's driving. Also John.
> >     Bob's driving, and he's also buying the food.

In formal writing, you may put *also* just about anywhere, and you *may* put *too* immediately after the added element. You may put either at the head of the clause:

> > Bob's driving. John, too, is driving. *or* John is driving also. *or* John, also, is driving.
> >     Bob's driving. Too, he's buying the food. *or* Also, he's buying the food.

All of these displacements are very formal, however, and should be used sparingly: perhaps only when needed to  point the structure of long propositions.

Comment: Placing *too* at the beginning looks very odd to my humble sextet of eyes. *Also* at the beginning is common, but frownded upon by certain style guides.

Comment: You can’t use that sense of *too* at the start of a sentence; it’s postpositive.

Comment: @tchrist  True, *OED 1* (fasc.Sep.1913) says, “Rarely, now never, used at the beginning of a clause”. But the 1987 Supplement reports “The use at the beginning of a clause has been revived, at first in the U.S” and provides citations from a trade publication, an academic reference work, UK and US newspapers, and popular fiction (Ludlum, *The Holcroft Covenant*).

Comment: @StoneyB Still sounds ungrammatical to me.

Comment: Too to me. I'm afraid I would correct my students.

Comment: @tchrist  Ungrammatical? Uncommon I'll grant you, but why not *too* alongside *also*, *in addition*, *what's more*, *moreover*, and other such adverbials? I don't much like it, except as a strong pivot; but it's an accepted formal use.

Comment: I stand by my words: it is ungrammatical / foreign / ungeneratable / alien to my ears, to the point of extreme bizarreness.

Comment: @tchrist  I'm glad somebody besides me reads with his ears. On the very rare occasions I use the construction I write it thus - *Too:*

Comment: It sounds more Victorian (Elizabethan, even!) to me, but here's ["Too, they demanded the right to vote..."](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22too+they+demanded+the+right%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). I think it's a clunky attempt to sound "formal/authoritative", but StoneyB's quite right that it does occur. I can't see why it should be ungrammatical, but it's probably "discriminated against" at the start of a sentence for the same reason as *Also* (per Cerberus above).

Answer (score 2):

Per my comment to the question, Google Books, and mine and TimLymington's "inner grammarians", all seem to agree that it's better to end the sentence with *is also*, rather than *also is*.

Personally, I think *"I am glad that Gabriel **is too**."* is much better, but I can't really explain why.

Comment: Shouldn't that be *my and Tim's?*  Not snarky, I'm genuinely unsure.

Comment: @TimLymington: I'm pretty sure that strictly/grammatically speaking it should be "my", but have a play with ["mine and john's"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22mine+and+john's%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) on Google Books (toggle between *my* and *mine*, try other common names, add things like *families* on the end, etc.). I think you'll find that in practice people actually use "mine" more often. And bear in mind that's the *written* form where people tend to ignore strict grammar. They probably do this even more in speech.

Comment: would either of the two downvoters care to give a *reason* here?

Comment: Drive-by shooting.

Comment: @Bill Franke: I guess maybe I just got hit by [a stray bullet](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/89835/2637) because I was the only "innocent bystander" around to take a pop at. I know my answer is a bit sparse in the "justification" department - but unless I'm much mistaken, the preference for **is too** (or at least, **is also**) is quite strong. I was expecting to have to dig a bit deeper if anyone questioned my position, but I can't feel motivated to do that simply because of anonymous downvotes.

Comment: +1 for *is too* and suggesting to switch to *is also*. I was going to suggest that (for the not-so-easily-explained reason for those two sounding better). (Also, upvoted because I don't see *anywhere* a ***valid reason*** for a downvote.)

Comment: It seems to me that all of us tacitly justify our answers based on our native-English-speakerhood & explicitly justify them by going to appropriate authorities for the context in which the Q arosen. Using language is an art as much as it is an inherently (but maybe not exclusively) human trait. Much of how we say what we say is based on aesthetic judgments: there are no rules for that, only reasons that all boil down to "_because I like it like that_". Your feeling about "also is" vs. "is also" is the same as mine: "is {also/too}" sounds better & more natural to me too.

Comment: @Bill Franke: I agree all of that except the *"justify them by going to appropriate authorities"* bit (unless you count Google Books as an "appropriate authority"). In this specific case, I've given next to no thought to the matter of *why* one word order is preferred over the other - I know what ***I*** prefer, and for now I'm content to back that up with usage figures showing I'm with the majority. To me, it's axiomatic that I'll tend to prefer what the majority do, because I acquire my "preferences" in the first place by reading and listening to what others write and say, not by "grammar".

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Sometimes it's necessary to cite a grammar book; sometimes to cite a famous author; sometimes to refer to Ngrams, etc. Some of, tchrist for example, consistently cites the OED; I consistently cite M-W; and so on. We all sometimes need support, but **I agree that preferences and feelings about what sounds and looks and feels good and right and normal come from reading and listening and practicing our own language skills, not from rulebooks**: That's what my first sentence means.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  What is attractive about this place is that almost everybody feels that way; you go NGrams, I go to OED and GB and UD not for 'authority' but for *evidence*. What divides us is that we all have read and practised different things; what unites us is that we embrace variety and difference rather than exclude it.

Comment: @StoneyB: There will always be cases where, as individual speakers, we don't share the same idiomatic preferences. But What I find most fascinating about ELU is the extent to which *competent* speakers do share preferences/prejudices. I don't see anyone here yet saying they prefer (or even, would *ever* use) "also is" at the end of a sentence.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: see the first comment (by JSBձոգչ) to the question. He said it's perfectly fine.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  I'll put *Too* at the front or *also.* at the back, but not *also is.* at the back. Random quirk. But I won't say *also is.* is ungrammatical.

Comment: @Roman Cheplyaka: True, but I read that as simply meaning he doesn't think "also is" is *ungrammatical* (I don't think anyone is suggesting it's not). My point here is that sticking just to the *also is/is also* issue, we all seem to prefer the latter - for whatever reason.

Answer (score 2):

While my immediate reaction was to reverse your usage (to "is also"), the strength of the sentence does seem to trail away.

You may prefer

> I am in favour of compromises and I am glad that Gabriel **concurs**.

Comment: I'd be much more likely to use **agrees** than **concurs,** which to me feels like a word that is becoming obsolete. But maybe that's because I'm American.