# Is it considered correct usage to end sentences with "is" or "are?

Tags: word-usage, syntactic-analysis, ellipses, be, sentence-ends

Sometimes, we need to end sentences with "is" or "are" to avoid repetition, but is it correct in formal language?

For example:

> Only error-free documents are taken seriously. I will make sure yours **is**.

Comment: The question is, “what will be ensured:  that it will be taken seriously or that it is error-free”

Comment: He/she, will make sure his/her document is error free, and therefore, taken seriously. Seems to be the comment of an editor, professional or otherwise.

Comment: Where do you think the problem..., I mean, if this is true, who told you it... ahem... Why do you think this is (the case)?

Comment: Is it correct? Yes, it is.

Comment: Deleting (ie missing out) the participle (etc) after an auxiliary may be considered to leave a fragment. But fragments are used extremely commonly in real life: 'Where's the remote? ... 'On the table.' ... 'Is the TV magazine there too?' ... 'Yes.' and/or 'It is.'

Comment: See [Is there a rule forbidding the use of “is” at the end of a sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/90687)

Answer (score 2):

It is perfectly valid syntax.  However, for various reasons the usage is discouraged (but not avoided entirely) in formal speech/writing.