# How do I correct this sentence? "I’m curious what you think the percentage is."

Tags: prepositions

I've been told not to end a sentence with a preposition, but I'm not sure how to correct this sentence:

> I’m curious what you think the percentage is.

I don't like the "is" at the end of the sentence. Would the following be better?

> I'm curious what you think is the percentage.

Comment: Your first example is the correct one, though it does not end with a prep, but with the auxiliary verb "is".

Comment: As I said before, the first sentence is the correct (or at least the usual) one. Incidentally, the element "what you think the percentage is" is a subordinate interrogative clause (embedded question).

Comment: Thanks @BillJ. I think you've answered my question. I thought the first way was somehow frowned upon. I guess I was wrong. :)

Comment: Not at all. It's the more natural of the two.

Comment: I think the preposition: 'curious **about**...', would help guide the reader/listener into the second clause, although omitting it is colloquial.

Comment: That's not a preposition. "Is" is a verb. This question is essentially a duplicate of [this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/90687/191178).

Comment: @Laurel, that [link](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/90687/is-there-a-rule-forbidding-the-use-of-is-at-the-end-of-a-sentence) you provided was extremely helpful to me. I would upvote your comment, if I could. :)

Answer (score -2):

The corrected sentence reads:

> "I am curious as to what you think the percentage is."

Ending with a preposition is not a hard and fast rule.

Comment: You don't say what is incorrect in the original. Corrections should be supported with authoritative sources. Is the original ungrammatical? Or is this more a matter of style?