# Can a gunfight happen when only one person has a gun?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, euphemisms

Dictionaries ([M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gunfight)) commonly define a *gunfight* as an exchange of gunfire.

However, the OED defines a gunfight as ["a shooting affray"](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/82559?rskey=xZuD4Q&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid2347981).  {paywall link}

Several stories & film describe or depict a gunfight where only a single combatant possesses / uses a gun, [such as in the 'classic' scene from Indiana Jones](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4DzcOCyHDqc).

Given such stories, is it reasonable to assume that a gunfight can involve 2+ people, where only one (presumably the winner) has a gun?  Would this be a *euphemism* for a certain kind of gunfight?

Comment: I wouldn't accept **gunfight** as an accurate description of a battle between two persons only one of whom had a gun. Would you?

Comment: @BillFranke OED seems to define it that way, and I see scenes like from the Indy movie, [and in the Untouchables](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0094226/quotes?qt=qt0439717) - so, yes.

Comment: I'll go with M-W: "[gunfight](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gunfight) a hostile encounter in which antagonists with guns shoot at each other."

Comment: As opposed to a friendly encounter in which antagonists with guns shoot at each other.

Comment: In a dogfight, is it necessary that _both_ the antagonists have dogs?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - planes, and yes. You can't be in a dogfight if you're grounded.

Comment: Can a gossiping happen if only one person is speaking gossip?  Yes; 'guilt by association'.  Not all of these situations are the same.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth: "Hostile" is as necessary in that definition as is the admonishment not to spread your spermicidal jelly on peanut-buttered toast in the morning. In any case, if you're shooting paintballs at each other, I'd still call it a "gunfight", but I'd leave out the "hostile". Paintball "kills" are as fragrant and benign as artificial flowers, only more interesting.

Comment: In a dogfight, it's **sufficient** that both antagonists **be** dogs -- of one kind or another. In a bitchfest, only one bitch  or bitcher is **necessary**. Sometimes a majority of one is sufficient.

Comment: @BillFranke it would also seem that only one person with a gun is sufficient to win a gunfight - the other(s) then are merely unprepared gunfighter(s).

Comment: A gunfighter without a gun can't participate in a gunfight. It's different from "**singular they/their/them**": concrete vs. abstract; reality vs. theory; bullets vs. bullshit. Two gunfighters with one gun = murder, IMHO. :-)

Comment: @BillFranke There exist plenty of film and literary references to fights involved two skilled fighters, where only one possesses a gun, *and the one with the gun does not always win.*

Comment: If the one without the gun wins, the it's not a gunfight, even if the initially gunless gunfighter shoots the other one with his own gun. To call such a struggle a _gunfight_ is essentially putting lipstick on the pig (cf. Humpty Dumpty): it may be _a fight over a gun_, but a "gunfight" is a battle in which both sides have guns. Is it a "fistfight" if fighter A has two arms and two fists and fighter B has no arms and no fists? No, it's some other kind of contest. One can always stipulate definitions beforehand, however: _War is Peace, Ignorance is Strength, Freedom is Slavery_. Problem solved.

Comment: Here's a recent [_Slate_ article](http://www.slate.com/articles/business/moneybox/2012/11/boehner_and_the_fiscal_cliff_the_house_speaker_is_bluffing_about_the_bush.html) that uses the gunfight metaphor. It cites an _Indiana Jones_ movie scene featuring a scimitar wielding fighter and Indy, who has a gun. Then it talks about John Boehner: "Boehner has brought a knife to a gunfight".

Answer (score 3):

Languages are not Math, they are a **Being**, they are **life**... You must not think a word means only what a dictionnary tells you; words mean what people want them to mean, *(and then when a high amount of people give them the same meaning, they acquire it)*. If you want that the 2+ people must have a gun, then call it that way, if not, call it "pseudogunfight".
Be creative, **words are magic!** =)

Comment: Yea, I think that's what we do on this site - sort out getting "a high amount of people give them the same meaning" :)

Comment: Words do not mean what people want them to mean; if that were so, there would be no need for translators, dictionaries or poets. Words mean what people *understand* them to mean.

Comment: If words meant whatever people want them to mean, there would be no language.

Comment: Once there are words, there is language: **Ego loquor, ergo sum**. "_'When I use a word,' Humpty Dumpty said, in rather a scornful tone, 'it means just what I choose it to mean — neither more nor less.'_
_'The question is,' said Alice, 'whether you can make words mean so many different things.'_ 
_'The question is,' said Humpty Dumpty, 'which is to be master — that's all.'_"

Comment: "words mean what people want them to mean" -- wonder if there's a need for more than one language in the world any more, or any "language" at all.

Comment: "Words mean what PEOPLE want them to mean". While using PEOPLE (instead of A PERSON), this gets full sense!. This is just the way our language envolves: an easier way of saying a word or an expression comes out, and people (some of them, not the whole world and not only one or two) start using it, till it becomes part of language (See this: http://www.dailywritingtips.com/bored-with-or-bored-of/). The same happens with words which change their meaning while time passes, or while it arrives to other countries. As I said, words are magic, so all what all of you said is completly true.

Comment: Whether words mean what people _want_ them to mean, or _understand_ them to mean, it's still possible that a word _doesn't_ mean what you want or expect. I've used words in rough drafts, double-checked a dictionary, and then thought, "Yikes! _That's_ not the word I want to use..." That said, I'll grant LuckyHorse this: sometimes dictionaries must play catch-up with culture (for example, some older print dictionaries may indicate that _gay_ means _cheerful_, and leave it at that).